# Wrong location of texture on the second triangle of BufferGeometry square

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I'm trying to add texture to a THREE.BufferGeometry. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/grz671u9/5/) is a working fiddle of what I'm accomplished so far.

This is my code:

```
var Test = new function () {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene(),
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(10, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000),
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true

    camera.position.set(-5, 5, 5);
    camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ';
    camera.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 4;
    camera.rotation.x = Math.atan(-1 / Math.sqrt(2));
    scene.add(camera)

    scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222));

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.7);
    camera.add(light);

    this.init = function () {
        $('body').append(renderer.domElement);
        Test.render();
    }
    this.render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(Test.render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    this.getScene = function getScene() {
        return scene
    }
}

var CreateSimpleMesh = new function () {
    var grassGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry(),
        grassVertexPositions = [],
        imageArray = [
            [0, 0],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [0, 1]
        ],
        image = new Image()

    this.init = function () {
        image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,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'
        var texture = new THREE.Texture();
        texture.image = image;
        image.onload = function () {
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
        };
        // first triangle
        grassVertexPositions.push([0, 0, 0])
        grassVertexPositions.push([1, 0, 0])
        grassVertexPositions.push([0, 1, 0])

        // second triangle
        grassVertexPositions.push([1, 1, 0])
        grassVertexPositions.push([0, 1, 0])
        grassVertexPositions.push([1, 0, 0])

        var grassVertices = new Float32Array(grassVertexPositions.length * 3),
            normals = new Float32Array(grassVertexPositions.length * 3),
            colors = new Float32Array(grassVertexPositions.length * 3),
            uvs = new Float32Array(grassVertexPositions.length * 2)

        for (var i = 0; i < grassVertexPositions.length; i++) {
            var index = 3 * i
            grassVertices[index + 0] = grassVertexPositions[i][0]
            grassVertices[index + 1] = grassVertexPositions[i][1]
            grassVertices[index + 2] = grassVertexPositions[i][2]
        }

        uvs[0] = imageArray[0][0]
        uvs[1] = imageArray[0][1]

        uvs[2] = imageArray[1][0]
        uvs[3] = imageArray[1][1]

        uvs[4] = imageArray[3][0]
        uvs[5] = imageArray[3][1]

        uvs[6] = imageArray[1][0]
        uvs[7] = imageArray[1][1]

        uvs[8] = imageArray[2][0]
        uvs[9] = imageArray[2][1]

        uvs[10] = imageArray[3][0]
        uvs[11] = imageArray[3][1]

        grassGeometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(grassVertices, 3))
        grassGeometry.addAttribute('normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute(normals, 3))
        grassGeometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3))
        grassGeometry.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(uvs, 2))

        grassGeometry.computeVertexNormals()

        //var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        //textureLoader.load('/img/testface.png', function (texture) {

            var grassMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: texture}),
                grassMesh = new THREE.Mesh(grassGeometry, grassMaterial)

            grassMesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
            Test.getScene().add(grassMesh)

            var helper = new THREE.WireframeHelper(grassMesh, 0xff00ff); // alternate
            helper.material.linewidth = 1;
            Test.getScene().add(helper);

            console.log(grassMesh.geometry.attributes)
        //});
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    Test.init()
    CreateSimpleMesh.init()
});
```

The problem is that texture on first triangle of the rectangle is correct but on the second triangle something strange is happening with the texture.

This is how it should look like [image]

This is how it look now [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these texture coordinates (same as x and y of vertex coordinates):

```
uvs[0] = 0
uvs[1] = 0

uvs[2] = 1
uvs[3] = 0

uvs[4] = 0
uvs[5] = 1

uvs[6] = 1
uvs[7] = 1

uvs[8] = 0
uvs[9] = 1

uvs[10] = 1
uvs[11] = 0
```